# Is it possible to not have a zero-indexed array with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been coming across some interview questions that mention within the question "... given an integer x and a zero-indexed array..." Is it necessary to mention zero-indexed array? What languages support non-zero-indexed arrays? Is it possible with javascript?

Comment: re "What languages support non-zero-indexed arrays?": see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist. Good ol' COBOL's one of them.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: Perl has supported non-0-based array indices for 25 years - and for almost that long, they have been heavily deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

An array in Javascript can be sparse where only some elements exist and the first element that exists does not have to be at index `0`.  But, the `.length` property is always measured from index `0`.

```
var array = [];
array[3] = "Hello";
array[9] = "Goodbye";

console.log(array.length);    // 10
console.log(array);           // [3: "Hello", 9: "Goodbye"]
console.log(array[0]);        // undefined
```

> Is it necessary to mention zero-indexed array?

It's not really necessary in Javascript since that is the default expectation, but does confirm that whatever values you are expecting in the array will start at the `0` index.